# jQuery dialog not open second time

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I am using jquery dialog box to edit product on Edit click. It is open on first product but not on second product while i am making a list for product

following is jquery dialog box code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 570,
        width: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function() {
                window.location.href = '<?=base_url()?>cart/remove_cart_prod/';
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#edit-item" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

and finally is my php code

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Edit <?=$prodname?>">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
        <form action="<?=base_url()?>cart/remove_cart_prod/" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <label for="size">Size</label>
            <select id="size" name="size" onchange="calculate(this)">
              <option value="">Choose Your Size</option>
                <?php
                    $sizequery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM size WHERE product_id = " . $proddata->id . " and status = 1");
                    if($sizequery->num_rows() > 0) 
                    {
                        foreach($sizequery->result() as $row) 
                        {
                            $prodsize = $row->size_from .' x '. $row->size_to;
                ?>
              <option value="<?=$prodsize?>" id="<?=$row->price?>"><?=$row->size_from?> x <?=$row->size_to?></option>
              <?php } } ?>
            </select>
            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
            <select id="quantity" name="quantity" onchange="calculate(this)">
              <option value="">Choose Your Quantity</option>
                <?php
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM quantity WHERE product_id = " . $proddata->id . " and status = 1");
                    if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
                    {
                        foreach($query->result() as $row) 
                        {
                            for($i = $row->quantity_from; $i <= $row->quantity_to; $i++)
                            {   
                ?>
              <option value="<?=$i?>" id="<?=$row->discount?>">
              <?=$i?>
              </option>
              <?php } } } ?>
            </select>
            <label for="color">Color</label>
            <select id="color" name="color" onchange="calculate(this)">
              <option value="">Choose Your Color</option>
              <option value="2">2 Color</option>
              <option value="3">3 Color</option>
              <option value="4">4 Color</option>
            </select>
            <label for="shippint_time">Shiping Time</label>
            <select id="shipping_time" name="shipping_time" onchange="calculate(this)">
              <option value="">Choose Your Shipping Time</option>
              <option value="0">Normal Shipping FREE</option>
              <option value="100">Express Shipping 100$</option>
            </select>
          </fieldset>
          <div class="pricebox">
            <p>Product Price: <span>$</span><span id="product_price"></span></p>
            <p>Product Discount: <span>$</span><span id="product_discount"></span></p>
            <p>Total Price: <span>$</span><span id="result"></span></p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- end dialog box -->
      <div class="six columns" style="padding:0px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="edit-item">Edit</a> | <a href="<?=base_url()?>cart/remove_cart_prod/<?=$item['rowid']?>" class="duplicate11" id="<?=$proddata->id?>">Remove</a> | <a href="<?=base_url()?>cart/duplicate_cart_prod/<?=str_replace(' ', '-', $prodname)?>/<?=str_replace(' ', '-', $item['size'])?>/<?=$item['qty']?>/<?=$item['price']?>/<?=$item['color']?>/<?=$item['shipping']?>/<?=$item['discount']?>" class="duplicate11" id="<?=$proddata->id?>">Duplicate</a></div>
```

dialog should open that specific dialog box when i click on "Edit"

Comment: `autoOpen: false` is need to change `true`

Comment: check your console and see if it has errors

Answer (score 0):

When the code `$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );` has been executed, the `#dialog-form` DIV is removed from the original position in HTML and appended at the last part of the body element.

Can you check the `#dialog-form` DIV can be shown even if the element moved into the last part of the body element?

If this is not the reason for the problem, could you see the javascript console if there is no javascript errors?

- Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux).
- Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.

Comment: this is my site: http://www.doitprinting.com/banners-printing on left side there is Place Your Order form, please fill this form and you are landed on cart page where on edit i implement this dialog code. on first product it is working fine but on second you will see the error